# is it possible to heal inflamed artieries after a CABG

Tags: inflammation, cabg-coronary-art-bypass

I am 48 years old and have recently undergone a bypass surgery on heart.

I am not a medical student but if its true ( correct me if i am wrong ), magnesium helps in healing inflammation in arteries. And because of inflammation plaque starts to stick to the walls of artery.

Is it possible to heal the inflamed arteries that caused blockage and that too after a bypass is already done.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to give medical advice here. However, the issue that they correct with a CABG is not inflammation of the arteries, it’s a buildup of plaque within the arteries in your heart.

A CABG usually occurs when the plaque is too extensive to simply open up the arteries with a stent, or a combination of stenting and CABG may be used.

Magnesium is an electrolyte. It is particularly important for the heart muscle, and, if too low (or too high), it can cause arrhythmias.

I don’t know anything about magnesium and inflammation, but I wouldn’t start any supplements or vitamins without consulting your cardiologist or surgeon.